# Spring boot design delete RESTful API through JPA got error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I need design delete API, but I got error. I still not get idea where was wrong.
Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value = "delete from product where productid = ?1")
    void deleteProductByProductID(int productID);
}
```

Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/{id}")
public @ResponseBody
    void deleteProduct(@PathVariable("id")int productID) {
    productRepository.deleteProductByProductID(productID);
}
```

API test error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-08T08:46:15.639+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "path": "/v1/product/delete/30"
}
```

IDE error:

> 2018-04-08 01:36:26.890  WARN 13629 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
>   S1009 2018-04-08 01:36:26.890 ERROR 13629 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Can not issue data
>   manipulation statements with executeQuery(). 2018-04-08 01:36:26.906
>   ERROR 13629 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract
>   ResultSet; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause

Comment: A `JpaRepository` already has a `deleteById` method. Why do you feel you need another one?

Comment: They are same, I knew it and I have try to use it, but I got same issues.

Comment: You need to add `@Modifying` to your method, as it is currently trying to execute an update using the wrong API. However, `deleteById` already knows better, so I doubt you're getting the exact same exception.

Comment: Sorry, I got mistake to copy and past my pice of code, I missed @Modifying.